# Unsuscribe every handler of an event

Tags: events, event-handling, dart

Can we cancel every subscriptions of a stream in one call?

In most of the dart examples, we can see that the main way to unsuscribe is to call the **Cancel** method directly from the [StreamSubscription](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html), but we need to store these Subscriptions...

```
var s = myElement.onClick.listen(myHandler); //storing the sub
s.Cancel() //unsuscribing the handler
```

Is there a way to cancel every Subscription of a given stream without storing them?

Something that could look like this:

```
myElement.onClick.subscriptions.forEach((s)=> s.Cancel());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a decorator pattern:

```dart
class MyStream<T> implements Stream<T>{

    Stream<T> _stream;

    List<StreamSubscription<T>> _subs;

    /*
       use noSuchMethod to pass all calls directly to _stream,
       and simply override the call to listen, and add a new method to removeAllListeners
    */

    StreamSubscription<T> listen(handler){
       var sub = _stream.listen(handler);
       _subs.add(sub);
       return sub;
    }

    void removeAllListeners(){
       _subs.forEach((s) => s.cancel());
       _subs.clear();
    }
}
```

if you wanted to use this on html elements you could do exactly the same decorator pattern on a `MyElement` by decorating `Element`. Example:

```dart
class MyElement implements Element{

    Element _element;

    /*
        use noSuchMethod to pass all calls directly to _element and simply override
        the event streams you want to be able to removeAllListeners from
    */

    MyElement(Element element){
        _element = element;
        _onClick = new MyStream<MouseEvent>(_element.onClick);
    }

    MyStream<MouseEvent> _onClick;
    MyStream<MouseEvent> get onClick => _onClick; //override the original stream getter here :)
}
```

Then use accordingly:

```dart
var superDivElement = new MyElement(new DivElement());
superDivElement.onClick.listen(handler);

//...

superDivElement.onClick.removeAllListeners();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the reference to be able to cancel the event.